# Filter-based feature selection for binary classification with unbalanced classes

Tags: classification, feature-selection, unbalanced-classes

I have a data set with ~10k observations and ~50 features. Each observation is assigned one of two classes (labeled 0 and 1, say). Approximately 98% of the observations are class 0, and the remaining 2% are class 1.

I would like to reduce the number of features to isolate the 5-8 most "relevant" features. Ideally, I want the selected features to be strongly correlated with the class label, but uncorrelated with each other.

(Next part might be suspect as I'm learning this on the fly) In essence, I'm just trying to gain insight on the data, so I want to use a *filter-based method*, which doesn't require introducing a model. For example, I tried penalized logistic regression, but then I have to select a penalty parameter, and I don't see how I can do this without introducing a model, doing CV, *etc*.

I tried using a one-way ANOVA (as implemented in sklearn [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.f_classif.html#sklearn.feature_selection.f_classif)). This seemed to "work", but I'm concerned that the [homoscedasticity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homoscedasticity) assumption is violated because of the class imbalance (the class 1 points have 2x-10x the standard deviation of the class 0 points).

Is there a go-to approach here?

Comment: Why don't you want to introduce a model?

Comment: @StephanKolassa Maybe I didn't phrase that well. I'm not sure yet what I'm ultimately going to do with this data (e.g. build a classifier, train a neural net, whatever), so there's not an obvious notion of training or testing error (in my mind). Because of that, I was hoping to stick to the data as closely as possible. I suppose I would be happy to use something like penalized LR if I could justify some reasonable way of picking the penalty parameter. Is this an unusual request?

Comment: Well, the first reaction of many people at CV will likely be to make some kind of assumptions and build a model... That said, a cross validation is very easy to set up using `cv.glmnet` in the `glmnet` package for R. ANOVA is really not appropriate for binary responses.

Comment: @StephanKolassa I see--thank you for the suggestion and comment about ANOVA. I will look at that package. Is there no standard way (for binary responses) of selecting/ranking features without building a model? It feels to me like a reasonable question, but I'm suspecting it may not be.

Comment: It depends on what kind of features you have. If you have only binary features, then you could set up separate contingency tables for all of them with the target variable, then choose the one that has the highest $\chi^2$ statistic. But after that, you are already a bit lost without a model. Should you continue with separate branches? (Then you are essentially building a classification tree.) Or use residuals in some way? (That requires a model.) If you have different types of features, you need to compare the "importance" in some way, which you could do, e.g., using a random forest.